# Name me, Who am I?

Tags: riddle, knowledge, rhyme, literature

I am who I am,
Returned to the world,
To Save or to Damn,
My banner's unfurled.

So many names I have,
But one always true.
No golden Calve,
But worship you do.

My people, they came.
Their weapon they bring.
Few know their true name,
And its familiar ring.

I did sneak away,
Now the battle is o'er.
Power, all that I say.
Who am I? Fear or adore?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's my guess:

I am who I am, Returned to the world,

> Rand al'Thor is the reincarnated Lews Therin, from the Wheel of Time series.

To Save or to Damn,
My banner's unfurled.

> Rand is ultimately responsible for the outcome of the Last Battle, win or lose. He fights under the Dragon banner for a large portion of the series.

So many names I have,
But one always true.

> Rand is called a lot of things, "The Dragon Reborn", "Lews Therin", "Car'a'Carn", but his name is Rand al'Thor.

No golden Calve,
But worship you do.

> Play on words. His golden dragon tattoos are on his forearms, not his calves. He's often worshipped by those who believe in the prophecies about him.

My people, they came.
Their weapon they bring.
Few know their true name,
And its familiar ring.

> This is the stanza I'm not sure about. It could mean several things. Asha'man bring Saidin as a weapon, but they don't know they were once all called Aes'Sedai. His friends come and fight with him, and on some level know about the whole Wheel reincarnation thing, but few are aware of what their names used to be in past lives.

I did sneak away,
Now the battle is o'er.

> After the last battle, he silently left his tent without his army noticing.

Power, all that I say.

> Rand gained some sort of unspecified superpower after the last battle. He cannot channel anymore, but can just will things to happen.

Who am I? Fear or adore?

> He switched bodies with Ishamael during the last battle, so if anyone recognized him it'd be as a villain. Those bonded to him can sense that he's still Rand.

Comment: The bit about his people refers to the Aiel. Their weapon would be the spear. Their true name, that few know, but rings familiar: they were once Tinkers. Everyone in that world knows about the Tinkers, but not that the Aiel were once part of them.

Comment: You've got it, and with a good explanation, so the tick goes to you!

Comment: Too bad Rand (the user) can't join the conversation.

Comment: For those of us unfamiliar with whatever book or movie this refers to, could you mention it in the answer?

Answer (score 4):

I am going to guess .....

> Jesus

Reasoning

> 1. He will return (also referred to as "the Great 'I am') 
>  2. He has many names 
>  3. He is not an idol, yet we worship Him 
>  4. A sword was brought to Gethsemane 
>  5. He did leave. 
>  6. But He left in Power

Comment: I'd go opposite on that.

Comment: Welcome to PSE. On riddles such as this, it is common practice to provide an explanation for either each line individually or groups of lines as appropriate. Can you explain more how you feel your answer fits?

Comment: Did as such. Thanks for the guidance.

Comment: +1 for a good attempt. Not quite though. The third stanza has some items that don't quite fit.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if this is right, but maybe

> [Paul Atreides](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_Atreides) from Frank Herbert's Dune.

I am who I am,
Returned to the world,
To Save or to Damn,
My banner's unfurled.

> He came to Arrakis and became the leader of the Fremen.

So many names I have,
But one always true.
No golden Calve,
But worship you do.

> He is also called Muad'Dib and Usul. He is worshipped by the Fremen like a god.

My people, they came.
Their weapon they bring.
Few know their true name,
And its familiar ring.

> The weapon of the Fremen might be either the sandworm or the [Weirding Module](http://dune.wikia.com/wiki/Weirding_Module). They use [Water Rings](http://dune.wikia.com/wiki/Water_Rings) (had to look that up).

I did sneak away,
Now the battle is o'er.
Power, all that I say.
Who am I? Fear or adore?

> He can use the [Bene Gesserit power of Voice](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bene_Gesserit).

Comment: Definitely a good try, but no. Look more at the names line. This person has one name that they are always known by.

Answer (score 3):

I've a guess.

> Is it Rand Al'thor, no one is sure if he will ruin the world or save it. Also he has many names but every body knows him as the dragon.

I am who I am,
Returned to the world,
To Save or to Damn,

> Because he is called as "the prophesied savior and breaker of the world"

My banner's unfurled.

> Because he reveals the Dragon Banner in fight against the Seanchan.

So many names I have,
But one always true.

> Because he has many names Dragon Reborn, Coramoor, Car'a'carn, He Who Comes With the Dawn, Shadowkiller, King of Illian, Lord of the Morning

My people, they came.
Their weapon they bring.
Few know their true name,

> Because he will bring Aiel.

Comment: Heh, what about rand al'thor the PSE user?

Comment: Welcome to PSE. Can you explain how this fits with the rest of the lines?

Comment: Ohhhh, I see how it fits, but I won't steal the answer :)

Comment: @AggieKidd  I've updated but someone has write a detailed answer before m.

Answer (score 2):

My guess:

> Any politician

Reasoning:

> I am who I am
>  Returned to the world, = every few years in America
>  To Save or to Damn, = depending on your party affiliation
>  My banner's unfurled. = yard signs, billboards, tv ads, etc.
>
>  So many names I have, = name-calling is common
>  But one always true. = their real name
>  No golden Calve,
>  But worship you do. = news is obsessed/we're obliged as citizens
>
>  My people, they came. = campaign volunteers are their people
>  Their weapon they bring. = their weapon is phonebanking
>  Few know their true name, = phone bankers are often anonymous
>  And its familiar ring. = but the ring of your cellphone is familiar
>
>  I did sneak away, = politicians often shirk responsibility after the election
>  Now the battle is o'er.
>  Power, all that I say. = a politician's word is powerful/bully pulpit
>  Who am I? Fear or adore?

Answer (score 1):

My attempt:

> Death

I am who I am, Returned to the world, To Save or to Damn, My banner's unfurled.

> He comes and goes. Some welcome him, many don't. Many organizations beckon him with their actions.

So many names I have, But one always true. No golden Calve, But worship you do.

> He has many names. Feared to the point of "worship," or feared similar to the way a god might be feared.

My people, they came. Their weapon they bring. Few know their true name, And its familiar ring.

> His people are soldiers or others. Literal weapons. Sound of war.

I did sneak away,
Now the battle is o'er.
Power, all that I say.
Who am I? Fear or adore?

> He comes and goes. Literal battle. He has power over life. Some adore him, many fear him.